# Show a "Bar" for zero results with morris.js

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, charts, bar-chart, morris.js

I'm using [Morris.js](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) to display data in charts, Id like to show a bar for every option, even if its zero, currently I get this:

[image: Current chart:]

As you can see the values for 'HIV Instant' for age group 21-25 and 26-30 are 0, how would I show a line (just a thin one) for each result? is this possible with Morris? I've searched the [docs](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html) for bar charts & searched google & SO but cant find anything? Any help is appreciated. Cheers

Here is the code for generating said chart:

```
// break up the object
var age_barParts = [];
$.each( results_by_age_chart, function(key , val){
    age_barParts.push({
        'test': key,
        'u16': val['u16'],
        '16-20': val['16-20'],
        '21-25': val['21-25'],
        '26-30': val['26-30'],
        '31-49': val['31-49'],
        '50+': val['50+']
    });
});
//build the graph
var age_bar = Morris.Bar({
    element: 'age_bar',
    data: age_barParts,
    xkey: ['test'],
    ykeys: ['u16', '16-20', '21-25', '26-30', '31-49', '50+'],
    labels: ["Under 16s", "16 to 20", "21 to 25", "26 to 30", "31 to 49", "Over 50s"],
    barColors: color_array,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: 'true',
    gridTextSize: 16,
    gridTextColor: '#5cb85c',
    xLabelAngle: '70',
    resize: true,
    padding: 40
});
```

Comment: which version of morris you were using ?

Answer (score 2):

In **Morris.js** there is no option to force drawing of a line for zero values, but you can set them to a very low non-zero value, for example 0.05.

Below an example with Morris:

```js
var age_barParts = [];
age_barParts.push({
      'test': 'HIV',
      'u16': 3,
      '16-20': 5,
      '21-25': 1,
      '26-30': 2,
      '31-49': 8,
      '50+': 2
});
age_barParts.push({
      'test': 'HIV Instant',
      'u16': 1,
      '16-20': 4,
      '21-25': 0.05,
      '26-30': 0.05,
      '31-49': 7,
      '50+': 3
});
var age_bar = Morris.Bar({
    element: 'age_bar',
    data: age_barParts,
    xkey: ['test'],
    ykeys: ['u16', '16-20', '21-25', '26-30', '31-49', '50+'],
    labels: ["Under 16s", "16 to 20", "21 to 25", "26 to 30", "31 to 49", "Over 50s"],
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: 'true',
    gridTextSize: 16,
    gridTextColor: '#5cb85c',
    xLabelAngle: '70',
    resize: true,
    padding: 40
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js"></script>

<div id="age_bar" style="height: 450px;"></div>
```

As alternative you can adopt [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) which has a specific [plotOption](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.column.minPointLength).

Below an example with Highcharts:

```js
$(function () {
    $('#age_bar').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'HIV stats'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['HIV', 'HIV Instant']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: '#'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
            minPointLength: 3
            }
        },
        colors: ["#0b62a4","#7a92a3","#4da74d","#afd8f8","#edc240","#cb4b4b","#9440ed"],
        series: [{
            name: 'u16',
            data: [1, 0]
        }, {
            name: '16-20',
            data: [5, 4]
        }, {
            name: '21-25',
            data: [1, 0]
        }, {
            name: '26-30',
            data: [2, 0]
        }, {
            name: '31-49',
            data: [8, 7]
        }, {
            name: '50+',
            data: [2, 3]
        }],
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="age_bar" style="height: 450px;"></div>
```

#### Update:

Here is a jsfiddle (for Morris) which modifies the hover legend replacing 0.05 with 0. You can improve this approach editing the `hoverCallback` function:

https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/zm8wt4pj/

Comment: Thank you, I did think of this but then the hover legend still shows a value of 0.5 so thought I would ask. I'll have a look at Highcharts as they look very similar

Comment: Just for example I updated my answer adding a fiddle which has an hoverCallback to adapt legends

Comment: That is not really good idea to hack the displayed result -need to adjust the API plus a customized hoverCallback for each charts...-, while it is quite easy to modify morris.js to implement this requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you compile from coffee script files, just add after `lastTop += size` in *morris.bar.coffee*

```
if size == 0 then size = 1
```

Otherwise, if you just want to modify the javascript file, just add after `lastTop += size;` in *morris.js*

```
if (size === 0) { size = 1; }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, I've tried adding this like so:
`_results1.push(lastTop += size);
 if (size === 0) { size = 1; }`
But it hasnt made a difference, I'm using CDNJS for raphael, will this make a difference? cheers!

Comment: I am afraid you are not modifying at the right place. I am developing a fork of Morris including that change, you can check the related commit: https://github.com/pierresh/morris.js/commit/c7d6fdd6d0114f36d1c621a961d4748aebdde6f1